# Transaction Isolation and many statement request

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I use serializable transaction isolation level and run a SQL query like:

```
CREATE DATABASE new_db;

use new_db;

CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

Will then `use new_db` fail as the `CREATE DATABASE new_db` statement is still not commited to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE DATABASE` is not allowed in a transaction.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx).

If this script was wrapped in an explicit transaction, it would throw an error on `CREATE DATABASE new_db`

Comment: @ta.speot.is I don't have a SQL database now, I'm just curious how transaction isolation works in theory.

Comment: Well if you wanted to know how it works *in theory* you don't need a database on hand...